# AUCTeX: global pdf mode stop working after typesetting error occurs

Tags: auctex, dvi-mode

Update:

I've tested the problem in detail, and the results are appended at the end of the question. I guess now the problem becomes: **How to avoid stupid diagnostic of AUCTeX when curly braces mismatch?**

---

Original question:

I have the following line

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-global-PDF-mode)
```

in my `~.emacs` that turns on global pdf mode by default. This way, by configuring TeXShop for external editor, I can use it as the previewer every time I `C-c C-c LaTeX` in emacs.

However, sometimes after a typesetting error occurs and `C-c (backtick)` is used to view error (details below), the pdf mode seems to be disabled. After fixing the mistake, dvi is generated rather than pdf, and the pdf never gets updated again. I need to exit emacs and restart to restore pdf mode.

Why does this behavior occur? Any fix? I'm using Emacs 24.3.0 with AUCTeX 11.87 (both are the current version).

---

Update:

The detailed workflow that triggers the problem:

1. Start emacs with a `.tex` file and `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-global-PDF-mode)` in startup file. The initial mode is `LaTeX/P Fill`, `LaTeX-mode` major mode, with `TeX-PDF-mode` and `auto-fill-mode` minor modes (that autofill mode may be due to my turning on auto fill in my startup file; I didn't test whether AUCTeX start with autofill by default).
2. Make a non-standard curly braces mismatch error, for instance,

   ```
   % header

   \begin{document}
     \MACRO{
   \end{document}
   ```

   where `\MACRO` is not a default macro, but maybe something defined in `% header` with `newcommand`. Still `LaTeX/P Fill`.
3. `C-c C-c RET` (use `LaTeX` to typeset by default). Error is reported:

   ```
   LaTeX errors in `*DIR/FILE output*'. Use C-c ` to display.
   ```

   Still `LaTeX/P Fill`.
4. `C-c (backtick)` to trigger function `TeX-next-error`. A strange buffer appears, named `TeX Live 2012`. The minibuffer below prompts for `options, RET:` At this time, the mode becomes `LaTeX Fill`; pdf mode is toggled away.
5. `C-g` to quit the function. The buffer is returned to the original editing buffer (but note that the `TeX Live 2012` buffer is still in the background; you will be prompted to save it when you try to quit emacs). Still `LaTeX Fill`.
6. Now fix the buggy code and `C-c C-c RET` again. This time, dvi is generated instead of pdf since now `TeX-PDF-mode` is `nil`.

Stray away: if I follow the prompts in step 4 instead of `C-g`, I will end up with the buffer `TeX Live 2012` containing

```
   \documentclass[OPTIONS]{CLASS}

   \begin{document}

   \end{document}
```

A new file! Well, not very helpful. I just missed one curly brace... And you ask me to rewrite the file... Nevertheless, the `TeX Live 2012` buffer at this time will be `LaTeX/P Fill`.

---

At last, a small working example that triggers this behavior:

```
    \documentclass{amsart}
    \newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}

    \begin{document}
    $\set{$
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if, instead, you use `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode)`

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for helping. No, it doesn't. My fault not testing the problem properly. I've pinned down the actual problem and record the details in the updated question statement.

Comment: It seems that the bug has been fixed? I had run into the same issue before, tried it again just now and couldn't reproduce the issue. (Running Emacs 26.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my setup and I never have had an issue over a compiling error.  I just fix whatever the error says and run it again.

```
(require 'tex-site)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTex t)
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                      
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                   
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                          
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                              
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-newline-function (quote newline-and-indent))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))) t)
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))) t)
)
```

You MWE doesn't cause the same issue when I run the code.  It might be your Emacs setup.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Indeed, using `custom-set-variables `(TeX-PDF-mode t)` instead of `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-global-PDF-mode)` solves the problem of PDF mode toggling. In this sense the problem is resolved. However, could you please tell me what error message you get when you use `C-c (backtick)` on the MWE? I still get that `TeX Live 2012` buffer; and only on the second run of LaTeX will it tell me `ERROR: File ended while scanning use of \set.` This is rather annoying.

Comment: @KevinSayHi so you want me to try to run latex, then after the error hit `C-c` and what is backtick?

Comment: You know, C-c ` for the error. (I can't type ` in code mode since it gets escaped.) Otherwise how do you obtain the error message?

Comment: @KevinSayHi my error messages split the screen and appear at the bottom after compilation.

Comment: Oh really? Unbelievable... That's not the default behavior of AUCTeX. So could you please remind me of what `'tex-site` is? Is it another add-on? That line doesn't work for me so I commented it out.

Comment: @KevinSayHi that is how you can load AucTex

Comment: I see. My AucTex is configured and activated by ELPA so I don't have that in my .emacs. By the way, what's your OS? I just googled error displaying issue and seems that this problem might be Mac specific.

Comment: @KevinSayHi I use linux and run it through the terminal not the GUI.  You need to set `(setq TeX-show-compilation t)`  I also don't compile with latex but with latexmk.

Comment: Yeah I also run it through terminal. Thanks for the `(setq TeX-show-compilation t)`. Exactly what I need!